# How to split string words with regexp_substr in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

```sql
select  
regexp_substr('a-b--->d--->e f','[^--->]+',1,1) col1
,regexp_substr('a-b--->d--->e f','[^--->]+',1,2) col2
,regexp_substr('a-b--->d--->e f','[^--->]+',1,3) col3
,regexp_substr('a-b--->d--->e f','[^--->]+',1,4) col4
 from dual
```

output

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | d | e f |

Required output

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a-b | d | e f |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select regexp_substr(value,'(.*?)(-+>|$)',1,1, NULL, 1) AS col1
,      regexp_substr(value,'(.*?)(-+>|$)',1,2, NULL, 1) AS col2
,      regexp_substr(value,'(.*?)(-+>|$)',1,3, NULL, 1) AS col3
,      regexp_substr(value,'(.*?)(-+>|$)',1,4, NULL, 1) AS col4
 from  table_name
```

or, if you are looking for the fixed delimiter string `--->` then you can use simple string functions (which are more to type but are likely going to be much faster):

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN pos1 = 0 THEN value
                     ELSE SUBSTR(value, 1, pos1 - 1)
       END AS col1,
       CASE
       WHEN pos1 = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN pos2 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(value, pos1 + 4)
                     ELSE SUBSTR(value, pos1 + 4, pos2 - pos1 - 4)
       END AS col2,
       CASE
       WHEN pos2 = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN pos3 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(value, pos2 + 4)
                     ELSE SUBSTR(value, pos3 + 4, pos3 - pos2 - 4)
       END AS col3,
       CASE
       WHEN pos3 = 0 THEN NULL
                     ELSE SUBSTR(value, pos3 + 4)
       END AS col4
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(value, '--->', 1, 1) AS pos1,
         INSTR(value, '--->', 1, 2) AS pos2,
         INSTR(value, '--->', 1, 3) AS pos3
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'a-b--->d--->e f' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a-b | d | e f | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJOvlVC8)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
 regexp_substr('a-b--->d--->e f','[a-z]+([ \-][a-z]+){0,1}',1,1) col1
,regexp_substr('a-b--->d--->e f','[a-z]+([ \-][a-z]+){0,1}',1,2) col2
,regexp_substr('a-b--->d--->e f','[a-z]+([ \-][a-z]+){0,1}',1,3) col3
,regexp_substr('a-b--->d--->e f','[a-z]+([ \-][a-z]+){0,1}',1,4) col4
 from dual
 ;

a-b d   e f (null)
```

Comment: Can  I replace a-z with others that it can a-z ,A-Z or special (&,@,#)

Comment: `[ \-]` will match space or backslash or hyphen. If you want to just match space or hyphen then you want `[ -]`. Also `{0,1}` can be simplified to `?`.

Comment: right: no need to escape - when used at that position.

Answer (score 0):

`[^--->]` is a [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so there is no point in specifying twice the same character in it.

A working regex is:

```
(-*[^->])+
```

That matches any character that is not an hyphen or a `>` with any number of possible trailing hyphens, and the pattern is repeated in a greedy way.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/AvASBM/1).